# How to transforrm a dataframe into 3 big rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How could I transform the following dataframe

Subject   A1    A2    A3

S001  24.0   25.0   25.0

S002  12.0   14.0   5.0

S003  10.0   12.0   3.0
...

into the following:

pax  score    facet

S001 24.0    A1

S002 12.0    A1

S003 10.0    A1

...

S001 25.0    A3

S002 5.0     A3

S003 3.0     A3

df=df.T is not working should I write a for loop?
Thank you for you help.

Comment: Use `df = df.melt('Subject', var_name='facet', value_name='score')`

Comment: yes this was the index

Comment: If need remove `O` columns `df.filter(regex='Subject|A').melt('Subject', var_name='facet', value_name='score')`